# Magento2: main.CRITICAL: exception category.product.type.details.renderers

Tags: magento2, exception

I am facing this exception on my exception log file, anyone familiar with this or any help?

```
[2017-03-09 06:35:23] main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'The element 'category.product.type.details.renderers' already has a child with alias 'default'' in /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:611
Stack trace:
#0 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php(319): Magento\Framework\Data\Structure->_insertChild('category.produc...', 'category.produc...', NULL, 'default')
#1 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ScheduledStructure/Helper.php(196): Magento\Framework\Data\Structure->setAsChild('category.produc...', 'category.produc...', 'default')
#2 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(115): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure\Helper->scheduleElement(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'category.produc...')
#3 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(84): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->buildStructure(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure))
#4 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#5 /home/myusername/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#6 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#7 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#10 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(509): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#11 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(467): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getElementAttribute('body', 'class')
#12 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Category/View.php(199): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->addBodyClass('page-products')
#13 /home/myusername/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Category/View/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View->execute()
#14 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->execute()
#15 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#18 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#21 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(106): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#24 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#27 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#30 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /home/myusername/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Category/View/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#33 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#36 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#37 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#40 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'searchautocompl...')
#43 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/mirasvit/module-search-autocomplete/src/SearchAutocomplete/Model/App/FrontController/Plugin.php(130): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Mirasvit\SearchAutocomplete\Model\App\FrontController\Plugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#46 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#48 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#49 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#50 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#51 /home/myusername/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#52 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#53 /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#54 /home/myusername/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#55 {main} [] []
```

due to this issue, my exception.log file is very larger, is any option to disable the exception log?.

Answer (score 0):

You or one of the extension installed, added again the default renderer in layout. You should inspect the modules, especially the layout files for product types, but not only in product type layout files.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. What would I necessarily be looking for in some of the extension layouts to pin point and remove to see if it fixes the issue? Thanks